# Microsoft Graph API - Class Notebooks

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, microsoft-graph-onenote

Using Microsoft Graph API, is it possible to create/load teacher and student pages from a Class Notebook?

I would prefer to not have to create a Teams assignment if possible but fine if that's the way I have to get around it.

Unfortunately the 'old' OneNote API is not an option for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [list pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onenote-list-pages?view=graph-rest-1.0) endpoint to retrieve a list of page objects. If successful, this method returns a 200 OK response code and a collection of page objects in the response body.
2. If you know the page Id, you can directly call the [get page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/page-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) endpoint. (If not, 1st call will help you with that.)
3. Use [create page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/section-post-pages?view=graph-rest-1.0) endpoint to create a new page in the specified section